# Frequent AzureADB2C/Account/error messages with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure AD B2C with my website. The problem occurs on the first sign in step, i.e. an unauthenticated user tries to access an authenticated page, and gets redirected to the Azure AD B2C site. 
The correct response is my custom page with login choices provided by B2C. This always works on Edge, but fails half the time on Chrome and Firefox.
The failure creates a redirect to the page provided by the Azure AD B2C middleware in my ASP.Net core 2.2 site.

Any ideas as to what this is?

Comment: After more investigation this seems to be related to https. I have the following in my startup.cs in asp.net core 2.2: 

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
So the site ought to always redirect to https. It does on Edge, but not on Chrome. Why?

Comment: Hi @Andy. Do you have `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` before or after `app.UseAuthentication()`? It should be before.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPadgett It is called before.